# Вивод тегов в шаблон, Django, Django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-template, django-view

я изучаю django пишу простой блог, и наткнулся на интересное приложение django-taggit, ознакомился с документацией но проблема появилась, нужно отобразить все теги(они привязаны к постам) которие есть в бд, без повторений
в шаблон, можете подсказать как именно отобразить в шаблоне все теги?

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    tags = TaggableManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**view.py**

```
def base(request):
    context ={
        'tags':Tag.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request,'blog/base.html',context)
```

**template.html**

```
<p>Tags list:

      {% for tag in tags %}
         <!-- display tags -->

      {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть у кого-то такая же проблема, я нашел способ ее решить, я просто не заметил или забыл о **urls.py**  я прописал код для view на другой маршрут по юрл.Если в кого такая проблема пишите, подскажу более точнее

Answer (score 0):

Tags list:

```
  {% for tag in tags %}
     {{tag}} # выводишь полученные теги

  {% endfor %}
```

Еще в класс Post добавь

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique='title', verbose_name='url')
```

таким образом можно сделать дружелюбные к поисковикам ссылки

Comment: Роман, спасибо за ответ, но этот способ не сработал :(

Comment: Вы во вьюхе не правильно создали функцию.
Tag.objects.all() - У вас нет класса Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Убери функцию во вьюхе.

```
Tags: {{ post.tags.all|join:", " }}
```

post.tags.all добавляет все теги данного поста, а join разделяет их, в нашем случае запятой.

Читайте [тут](https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/glava-2-uluchshenie-bloga-s-pomoshyu-rasshirennyh-vozmozhnostej/dobavlyaem-tegi.html)

Comment: Я ето уже находил) Спасибо, но мне нужно именно все теги которые есть, отобразить  в шаблоне без повторений